# iPad application crash in Apple review - cannot replicate in simulator, have crash log

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash, crash-reports

I am clearly missing something obvious here and would really appreciate some input.  I have tried repeatedly to submit an application to Apple (iPad in this case) that is crashing on their end when testing but I cannot replicated the situation on my end (obviously I only have the damned simulator to work with at this point).

The crash log is as follows:

```
Date/Time:       2010-04-01 05:39:47.226 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.2 (7B367)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000790a0 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00079090 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00079082 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008d20a abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00044a1c __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000057c4 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042dee __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042e42 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042f12 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000046a4 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00090c6e +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 74
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00090d38 +[NSException raise:format:] + 28
12  Foundation                      0x00002600 -[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:] + 184
13  iPadMosaic                      0x00003282 -[iPadMosaicViewController getAlbumThumbs] (iPadMosaicViewController.m:468)
14  Foundation                      0x000728fe __NSFireDelayedPerform + 314
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00022d1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 2092
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000224da CFRunLoopRunInMode + 42
17  GraphicsServices                0x000030d4 GSEventRunModal + 108
18  GraphicsServices                0x00003180 GSEventRun + 56
19  UIKit                           0x000034c2 -[UIApplication _run] + 374
20  UIKit                           0x000019ec UIApplicationMain + 636
21  iPadMosaic                      0x00002234 main (main.m:14)
22  iPadMosaic                      0x00002204 start + 32
```

My understanding here is that I am botching the Dictionary add somehow.  The relevant lines of code are:

```
for (NSDictionary *album in self.albumList) {
    // Get image for each album cover

    UIImage *albumCover;

    // Loop through photos to get URL of cover based on photo ID match
    NSString *coverURL = @"";
    for (NSDictionary *photo in self.photoList) {
        if ([[photo objectForKey:@"pid"] isEqualToString:[album objectForKey:@"cover_pid"]]) {
            coverURL = [photo objectForKey:@"src"];
        }
    }


    NSURL *albumCoverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:coverURL];
    NSData *albumCoverData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:albumCoverURL];
    albumCover = [UIImage imageWithData:albumCoverData];    

    if (albumCover == nil || albumCover == NULL) {
        //NSLog(@"No album cover for some reason");
        albumCover = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noImage.png"];
    }

    [[self.albumList objectAtIndex:albumCurrent] setObject:albumCover forKey:@"coverThumb"];
}
```

This is part of a loop that runs over the existing dictionaries stored in an array.  If retrieving the album cover fails for some reason the object is filled with a default image and then added.  The last line of the code is what's showing up in the crash log.

It runs fine in the simulator but crashes 100% in testing on device apparently.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 4):

If Foundation isn't radically changed in from 3.0 to 3.2, then there's only 3 cases an exception is raised in `-setObject:forKey:`:

1. mutating method sent to immutable object
2. attempt to insert nil value
3. attempt to insert nil key

Obviously the 3rd case is impossible, so you only need to check:

1. Is `[self.albumList objectAtIndex:albumCurrent]` guaranteed to be an NSMutableDictionary?
2. Have you forgotten to include `noImage.png` in submission?

Comment: The image file is in the Resources folder.  I am wondering about the first option now.  I am taking in a result from a web request and storing it in an NSMutableArray.  Is it possible that the dictionary in the array I am receiving is somehow not mutable?

Do I need to iterate in detail through the result and build from scratch a new array/dictionary that is mutable?

Would this work in the simulator and not in the device?  When I dump the dictionary in question to NSLog before and after the attempt to add the object it looks great in the simulator.  The UIImage object is there for the key.

Comment: *Is it possible that the dictionary in the array I am receiving is somehow not mutable?* — depends on how the library is written. Make a `-mutableCopy` to ensure it is mutable.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem!  It was a case sensitivity issue...make sure that the file named noImage.png matches the actual file...not NoImage.png or noimage.png...check all of your images!  I missed out on the app store opening because of 1 letter on 1 file!